# Append JSON output to input box and label one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have output from JSON like this

```
{"name":"blue tshirt","category":"t-shirt","size":"XS,S,M,L,XL"}
```

this code where output come from

```
$parameters = array(':id'=>$id);
$so_result = $this->ModelProduct->GetData($parameters);
print_r (json_encode($so_result,true));
```

and i use ajax to append the output/result

```
    var data={id:id};
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        url:"",
        data:data,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data) {
                $('#name').val(data);
        }
    });
return false;
```

and i won the result show in form like this

```
Name : <input type="text" id="name" value="blue tshirt" >
Category : <input type="text" id="category" value="t-shirt">
Size : 
<label>XS</label>
<label>S</label>
<label>M</label>
<label>L</label>
<label>XL</label>
```

whether it can? and how to do it. because until now I can not break it down and always appear in one input box.

Comment: may i know what is there in data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get specific properties out of JSON and assign to your DOM elements. Change you ajax section to

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        url:"",
        data:data,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse( data );
                $('#name').val(data.name);
                $('#category').val(data.category);
                var sizes  = data.size.split( "," );
               for(var counter  = 0; counte < sizes.length; counter++)
               {
                  $('#category').parent().append("<label>" + sizes[ counter ] + "</label>");
               }
        }
    });
```

or simply

```
$.getJSON( "url", function( data ) {
     alert(data);//to check the data first
     $('#name').val(data.name);
     $('#category').val(data.category);
     var sizes  = data.size.split( "," );
     for(var counter  = 0; counte < sizes.length; counter++)
     {
        $('#category').parent().append("<label>" + sizes[ counter ] + "</label>");
     }
});
```

Comment: @gurvider372, thankyou but if i use (data.name) the input box no display result, and if i use alert(data.name) give result undefined

Comment: @riskimaker what does alert(data) says?

Comment: @gurvider372, alert(data) says -> {"name":"blue tshirt","category":"t-shirt","size":"XS,S,M,L,XL"}

Comment: @riskimaker in that case you need to convert it to a JSON object first, if it is not already.

Comment: @riskimaker put data = JSON.parse( data ); before first line inside success handler

Comment: @gurvider372, Thankyou turned out to easy just add data = JSON.parse( data ); and solved

Comment: @riskimaker thanks for accepting the answer. Happy to help. Don't forget to upvote the answer if they have helped you.